# How to get Material-UI Date Picker value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-redux, material-ui

I am using material-ui datepicker. What i am trying to do is get the value selected by the user and set it to state however i am struggling to figure this out so any help would be much appreciated.

So here is what i am doing at the moment:

My datepicker component looks like this:

```
<DatePicker
  hintText="Select the date"
  formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
  onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)} />
```

the handleChange1 function:

```
handleChange1(e, date){
 this.setState({
   appointmentDate: date.value
})
 console.log(e, date);
 console.log(this.state.appointmentDate;
}
```

The Constructor:

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   appointmentDate: '',
   appointmentTime: ''
 };
```

All of the above give me the following in the console....

```
null Fri Oct 20 2017 16:50:33 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

AND

```
 _blank log_
```

However, in the textfield once the user selects the date i can see the date being rendered correctly like 20-10-2017

The date being displayed to the user is what i want to store to state.
Can someone explain how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you are getting the date you are just missing the formatting
when you have this information "Fri Oct 20 2017 16:50:33 GMT+0100 (BST)"
do something like this

```
      var date = new Date("Fri Oct 20 2017 16:50:33 GMT+0100 (BST)")
      var finaldate = date.getDate() + '-' +  (date.getMonth() + 1)  + '-' +  date.getFullYear()
```

at the end you will have finaldate = "20-10-2017"

hope this helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the Date-Picker into a controlled input. The object with which the Date-Picker can bind is a Date object. So your initial state should look like

```
this.state={appointmentDate:null}
```

Then you can bind your date with the following control.

```
 <DatePicker
      hintText="Select the date"
      formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
      onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)} 
      value={this.state.appointmentDate}/>
```

with the handlechange function being

```
handleChange1(e, date){
    this.setState({
       appointmentDate: date
    });
}
```

If you want to store the formatted string of the date as a separate entry in your state, you can do so using the handleChange1 function

```
handleChange1(e, date){
        this.setState({
           appointmentDate: date,
           appointmentDateString:  moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        });
    }
```